# Four points, $A$, $B$, $C$ and $D$, are such that $AD \perp$ $BC$ and $BD \perp AC$. Show that $CD \perp AB$.

Tags: vectors

I can't prove this algebraically.

Four points, $A$, $B$, $C$ and $D$, are such that $AD \perp$ $BC$ and $BD \perp AC$. Show that $CD \perp AB$.

$AD . BC  = 0$

$BD . AC  = 0$

$CD . AB  = $

I've tried putting $CD$ in terms of the other vectors but I can never seem to get anything that simplifies. Can anyone help please?

Answer (score 1):

We have
$$0=AD\cdot BC=AD\cdot(BD+DC)$$
and 
$$0=BD\cdot AC=BD\cdot(AD+DC).$$
Subtract the two right-most terms gives the answer.

Comment: Could you please include the last step. I can't see how  $AD.(BD+DC) - BD.(AD+DC)$ simplifies to $CD.AB$

Comment: It simplifies to $AD\cdot DC-BD\cdot DC=(AD-BD)\cdot DC$.

Answer (score 0):

In triangle $ABC$, $D$ is the intersection of two altitude $AD$ and $BD$, so the third altitude also pass through $D$, showing $CD\perp AB$.

In the case of $3D$, let $D'$ be the projection from $D$ to plane $ABC$ then since $AD\perp BC$ and $D'D\perp BC$ we have plane $ADD'\perp BC$ so $AD'\perp BC$, similarly $BD'\perp AC$ and hence by orthocenter $CD'\perp AB$. Now $CD'\perp AB$ and $DD'\perp AB$ showing plane $CDD'\perp AB$ hence $CD\perp AB$.

Comment: $D$ need not even be coplanar with $A,B,C$. Consider a regular tetrahedron.

Comment: If we are working with $3D$ geometry, then a projection from D to plane $ABC$ would do the trick.

Answer (score 0):

let the vectors $a,b,c,d$ represent $OA,OB,OC,OD$

then $AB=b-a$ etc.

the orthogonality of $AB$ and $CD$ gives you:
$$
(b-a)\cdot(d-c) = 0
$$

write a similar equation for the other given orthogonality relation. now eliminate the terms in common in the two equations, and from the four products remaining, rearrsnge to derive the third equation you require

Comment: sorry about the spelling mistake. still can't edit answers due to the rendering bug introduced at the last upgrade. that's why i don't visit MSE very often these days.